# Erros when using getting JWT headers jwt.get_unverified_header

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, jwt

I am using Google Cloud function, my code:

```
@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(event):
   print('---------')
   jwt_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(event)
   print(jwt_header)
```

The error I am getting is :

```
jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Invalid token type. Token must be a <class 'bytes'>"
```

To debug, I tried this on my local(mac+PyCharm) and the same code works , I am able to retrieve the JWT header

[image]

Has anyone seen this? Why is this failing on goolge cloud function ?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example the `event` is a [Flask `Request` object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.Request). The error message is saying that the method `get_unverified_header` is expecting `bytes`. You need to extract the jwt token from your request and then pass it to `jwt.get_unverified_header(jwt)`.

If your JWT is passed to the request in an authorization header like so:

```http
GET /protected HTTP/1.1
Authorization: JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZGVudGl0eSI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNDQ0OTE3NjQwLCJuYmYiOjE0NDQ5MTc2NDAsImV4cCI6MTQ0NDkxNzk0MH0.KPmI6WSjRjlpzecPvs3q_T3cJQvAgJvaQAPtk1abC_E
```

You could retrieve it with something like:

```py
@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
   jwt_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
   if jwt_header:
       token = jwt_header.split(' ', 1)[1].encode()
       jwt_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(encoded_jwt)
```

Comment: The token is not being passed as a header. I am getting the token back from Google API here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#python 
In here input to the google cloud function is a token in itself. This token is of the type <bytes>. So, .split operation won't work

Comment: The cloud function you are using [`@functions_framework.http`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#http_frameworks) provides a flask Request object to your function. It's triggered by an HTTP request. It's not clear by your question if you have an external process triggering this cloud function via HTTP request or if you need to register a different cloud function triggered by something like cloud_event, ex: `@functions_framework.cloud_event`